# Is it ok to cut off the older leaves of an avocado plant?

Tags: pruning, avocado

I  have an avocado plant which I grew from seed, and it already has a lot of leaves. The thing is, my pot isn't that big, so I was wondering whether it will be alright to cut off the older leaves in the bottom?

The older leaves are turning yellow and brown in the edges a week ago, and I added nitrogen fertilizer (not sure that this will work).

Picture:

[image: avocado plant, pot too small]

Comment: Hi! Would you please post a few pictures of your plant, including the whole thing, the base where the big  leaves are at the bottom and the pot? If you have any trouble doing that, just leave a note and someone will help you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your avocado needs a bigger pot, then it would be best to go and get a bigger pot. Cutting off some leaves won't help the situation - the plant won't be able to continue to grow or remain healthy if it doesn't have enough room at the root. Roots are very important; any plant is only as healthy  as its roots, and removing some leaves just means your plant has fewer leaves, it won't stop the plant from becoming stunted.

If the older leaves are changing colour and going brown, the plant has decided to sacrifice those in order to try to survive, so they will probably fall off anyway. If you do not give it a new pot, you may soon end up with a bare stalk with a little tuft of leaves at the top...

Comment: How do we replant it? I had some plants before, and whenever I try to replant them, they die. So I'm scared of doing this.

Comment: Okay - first, can you post a photograph of your plant, showing the pot its in as well? I just want to make sure it does actually need a bigger pot before giving advice on how to repot...

Comment: I posted the picture

Comment: It doesn't look like its in too small of a pot - turn it out and see what it looks like. Do that by placing the fingers of one hand either side of the mainstem, against the soil to support it, turn up side down and gently remove from the pot. If it won't come out,  press with both hands all round the pot, try again and tap the bottom of the pot sharply a few times. If there's roots hanging out the bottom, just get a new, larger pot first and some potting soil before turning out of its pot. Repot at the same level (soil not higher up the stem when done) video here https://youtu.be/tBPy16xR03w